# Can an outside 13A socket gang be connected via a new junction box on an existing outdoor supply?

Tags: electrical, wiring, receptacle, 240v, uk

This is in the UK. We have a 240V outside electrical supply via a dedicated consumer unit:

[image]

The cable is 3 CORE BS5467 XLPE SWA ARMOURED CABLES 600/1000V
https://www.powerandcables.com/product/product-category/3-core-bs5467-awa-armoured-cables-600-1000v/

This supplies a juccuzi/hottub in the garden, which is rated at 20A. We would now like to have a 13A outside plug socket near the jaccuzi:

[image]

https://www.amazon.co.uk/Onlyonehere-Weatherproof-Waterproof-Switched-Electrical/dp/B08SWDS8X1

The question is: Can this be connected via the existing cable that supplies the jaccuzi, or does it require it's own supply from the exterior consumer unit in the first picture ?

Comment: If the hot tub connection/junction box has a opening for another cable, then should be able to add from there if local code allows.  Using the jaccuzi and the outlet at same time, might overload the circuit, and you might want to add the outlet to it's own supply.  Local code might say jaccuzi can be the only thing on that circuit and need a new circuit for extras.

Comment: The only thing the sockets will be used for is charging mobile phones and tablets.  There is a junction box for the jacuzzi but it is not easily accessible - I was hopeing that a junction box can be inserted in the existing armourded cable, near where we need the sockets ?

Comment: That is easy to do.  The only thing that would stop you is your local electrical code saying you cannot.  Need to check if you have enough loose cable to pull into new box to make new connections or need to add new cable from new box to jaccuzi or to supply box.  Usually need 4 to 6 inches(10 to 15cm) for each end at cut.

Comment: Show a picture of every existing outlet on the wire. It would be fair to forewarn you that, even if it's permitted, adding a new waterproof socket to an existing armored cable circuit is not for the inexperienced. It would likely be far cheaper to pay an electrician to do it and you go do whatever it is you do best to earn money, than you take whatever amount of time it will take you to break into this circuit with a waterproof glanded outlet box. A competent professional should be able to do it in an hour. They will also be able to ensure it's grounded proeprly; vital from what you describe

Comment: The outdoor box you linked is a Chinese counterfeit.  Don't buy electrical gear on Amazon or mail order generally, unless it is wickes.co.uk...

Comment: @CaiusJard I am intending to hire a electrician and I've had some quotes - these range from £40 to £180 (plus materials) depending on whether they have to run a new cable from the box. 2 tradesmen have said it has to be a new wire to comply with the regulations, whereas the 3 cheaper ones say that a spur can be taken off the existing one. A whole day's work compared to 2 hours (or so they said).  Plus, there is a lot of additional cost of materials for the higher quotes since that involves 20m of outdoor cabling and fixtures. As for a pictuire of every outlet - there is only 1 - the hot tub.

Comment: @Harper-ReinstateMonica Thank you for that - I was unaware - is it not up to spec ? Can you recommend a good one ? Would this be better ?
https://www.wickes.co.uk/Masterplug-IP66-13A-Twin-Exterior-Switched-Socket---Grey/p/117857

Comment: Yes, because it has a bricks and mortar presence in the UK, Wickes must answer to the British authorities re: the products sold being properly inspected and certified (e.g. BSI mark).  Amazon has no such obligation, *especially since most of their items are "third party sellers"* - basically Amazon has become eBay.

Comment: I'm sure there is more than one electrical retailer in the United Kingdom; you talk like Wickes is the only one. Even "don't buy off eBay/amazon" is imho poor advice. "Be aware that a significant majority of cheap electrical equipment on eBay/amazon is low quality Chinese carp that doesn't conform to local regulation. Be diligent in researching your retailer" is a more reasonable statement.

Comment: @CaiusJard Wrong. You are wildly underestimating both the importance of this, and the difficulty of discerning. You are like "Well it fails to cross some government T's and dot some I's" *this stuff kills*.  And Amazon particularly obfuscates the difference because they're optimizing for "making the most money". And *even if the consumer was aware* about Marketplace and shunned it, the fakers are using "commingling" to contaminate Amazon's own supply.   **This is a super hard problem** and don't naysay it just because you're not up to speed.

Comment: @CaiusJard - thanks. Do you know whether we will have to get a seperate circuit for the socket, or whether they can just take a spur off the armoured cable. With the cost of materials, it's something like £260 vs £60

Comment: And any competent **bricks and mortar** retailer (that isn't an obvious junk shop) will have certified, quality product, because the government has the reach to enforce there.  What I am saying is, if you MUST mail-order, do so with firms who are *primarily* in the bricks-and-mortar business, and will be shipping from their government-vetted retail supply chain.

Comment: @Harper-ReinstateMonica I get like that sometimes; so beaten down and utterly despairing and the universe's limitless capacity to provide vastly improved challengers despite my best efforts to make every solution foolproof. I normally take it as a sign it's time to take a break from SE. That subsequent advice is more balanced; buy online, even from eBay if you're certain it's e.g. Wickes' eBay store. The OP is getting a professional to do the work; anyone in their right mind and interested in working to code will refuse to fit carp.

Comment: @RobertLong by and large, trying to find parts that you will hand to an electrician to fit is something of a false economy. These guys do the job over and over, they get to know the kit available from their preferred brand, they have a stack of related parts in their job box - if you hand them some chinese crap that falls apart as soon as they try and hammer out the knockout hole then you're left with a non returnable thing, and they have to buy one anyway. For the guys that have said they can do it cheap, make sure they aren't just saying that and then jacking the price after.. and equally

Comment: bear in mind that the "big job mate, here's a high quote" might be doing it to price the work out because they're so busy they don't want it (construction is crazy busy right now - something about the pandemic meaning people spent years looking at 4 walls and are sick of it/motivated to get that work done)

Comment: *Do you know whether we will have to get a seperate circuit for the socket, or whether they can just take a spur off the armoured cable* - from what I know of the certification, the electrician will do the work and certify to the local authority that it is of the required standard if necessary. I don't believe that adding an outlet to a circuit is necessarily work that has to be notified to the authority but it has to be done in a competent manner, so is best left to a professional, especially as you're actively saying you want to position an electrical outlet near something you bathe in..

Comment: To some extent wiring isn't hard - there are rules governing what wire sizes and what kinds of protective devices they should have, and the protective device should be capable of preventing current flow that will overheat the wire and cause a fire. The cable you have has a 20A breaker for a reason - to protect the cable. How much capacity the circuit has left for running things other than the spa is something your professional will determine and install as appropriate. It might be that your spa is using all the capacity and adding an outlet will cause frequent nuisance tripping but you can't

Comment: just replace the breaker for a bigger one if the cable cannot carry the load (and it's not a simple "it is size X so it can do Y" - the surroundings have a significant effect on the capacity of a cable. Your professional will be able to assess all of this, plus the usage pattern of the cable, and make an assessment of what is appropriate. You might never plug more than a cellphone charger in but someone else might come and plug in two electric heaters..

Comment: @CaiusJard You raise a good point that if you're only tire-kicking and the pro will select the product, that it doesn't matter what you look at.  That depends, however, on the pro *being* a pro.  Those are hard to find of late.  I think OP's pivotal question is whether it's alright to add sockets to the hot tub circuit (i.e. can a dedicated circuit with a large hardwired load have sockets too),  and I think OP will need to supply the photos you requested.

Comment: @CaiusJard thanks again this is very helpful. I wasn't suggesting that I am going to supply the materials myself. When I get a quote I always ask for the cost of labour and materials to be seperate, so I know what I am paying for. As for capacity, I think what you are saying is that if a qualified electrician says they can take a spur and provide the relevant certificate, then that should be fine (especially since there are 3 contractors saying that's fine, and only 2 saying it has to be a seperate circuit ?) I just don't get why others say it's not OK. Are the regs subject to interpretaion ?

Comment: @Harper-ReinstateMonica thanks for that. As I mentioned in an earlier comment, the only device on the circuit is the hottub - I can post a picture of it if needed, but is that actually of any use ?

Comment: Yoid probably be better off asking the relevant contractor why they decided what they did. Perhaps they looked at the tub and saw it is a heater/pump with a large power requirement. Perhaps they are viewing the circuit as feeding a fixed appliance in a similar way to a cooker/oven. Perhaps the others regard it as more like a washer or dryer; motor and heater with intermittent use that can share a circuit. One thing is for sure; regardless what a person on the internet says, the contractor on your site, looking at the setup and putting their name on the dotted line can see what we can't :)